# To find the determinant of a 4×4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any short method to find the determinant of a $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix?

I've been solving this from the method that of $3  \times 3 $ matrix but this is going quite lengthy!!
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1+x & 1+x \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1+x & 0 & 1+x \\ 1 & 1+x & 1+x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I know how to solve it for finding determinant...But it takes time.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html

Comment: You might consider doing elementary row operations on the matrix first, keeping track of how whatever operations you used will affect the final determinant.  Alternatively, remember that you may use [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along *any* row or column, not just the top row.

Comment: But I have a matrix of 4×4 which consists of a variable....

Comment: Please give us the matrix - then you will see what can be done.

Comment: "*But I have a matrix of 4x4 which consists of a variable...*"  So?  Treat the variable exactly the same as you do any other number, (*with the exception that you are not allowed to divide by it for fear of division by zero errors*).  The only difference is that in your arithmetic you won't be able to combine everything into a single term like you would if there were no variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the first and second columns to get a symmetric matrix. This negates the determinant. My determinant is $-3(1+x)^2,$ so the answer to your question is $$ 3(1+x)^2. $$

Horn and Johnson call this *diagonalization by congruence*. The additional detail is that I have arranged $\det P = 1,$ to have the same deteminant.
It turns out that we save space by writing $$ t = 1 + x.  $$
**I suggest you confirm the matrix identity, by hand.**

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - t & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -   \frac{ t }{ 2 } &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & t & t \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
t & 1 & 0 & t \\ 
t & 1 & t & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - t &  -   \frac{ t }{ 2 } \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 t & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{3 t }{ 2 } \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Here are $x=5,6,7,$ or $t=6,7,8.$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 6 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 6 & 6 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
6 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\ 
6 & 1 & 6 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 6 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 12 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 5 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 12 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 6 & 6 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
6 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\ 
6 & 1 & 6 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 7 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 7 & 7 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
7 & 1 & 0 & 7 \\ 
7 & 1 & 7 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 7 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 14 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 14 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 4 & 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 6 & 6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 7 & 7 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
7 & 1 & 0 & 7 \\ 
7 & 1 & 7 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 8 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 4 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 8 & 8 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
8 & 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 
8 & 1 & 8 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 8 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 7 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 7 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 7 & 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 8 & 8 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
8 & 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 
8 & 1 & 8 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: .Got it. Thankyou. But I was just looking for any short method for solving this if any. But yours is simpler than that of mine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @demon  I typed in the matrix identity in terms of a new variable $t = 1 + x.$ Suggest you confirm the matrix identity by hand. It is easy enough to see $\det P = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

You may find interesting to use Hamilton-Caley Formula:

$$\text{det}\mathsf{A} = \frac{1}{24}\left\{(\text{tr}\mathsf{A}^4 - 6\text{tr}(\mathsf{A}^2)(\text{tr}\mathsf{A})^2 + 3(\text{tr}\mathsf{A})^2 + 8\text{tr}(\mathsf{A}^3)\text{tr}\mathsf{A} - 6\text{tr}(\mathsf{A}^4)\right\}$$

Comment: Is there a difference between $(\text{tr}\mathsf{A})$ and $[\text{tr}\mathsf{A}]$?

Comment: @Henry Turing. I will try for this.